# Como pegar as manchetes das Olimpíadas no site da CNN com Python usando BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping

Gostaria de um exemplo de como pegar as manchetes das Olimpíadas em http://edition.cnn.com/sport/olympics

usando BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A questão é saber olhar para o html retornado do *[get request](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)* e identificar o que quer, neste caso queremos todos os `<span>` que tenham a class `cd__headline-text`, presumo que com 'manchetes' se refira a isso. Pode fazer assim:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
import requests as r

req = r.get('http://edition.cnn.com/sport/olympics')
soup = bs4(req.text, 'html.parser') # req.text = html retornado
manchetes_html = soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'cd__headline-text'}) # aqui vamos procurar no html por aquilo que eu disse acima, e teremos uma lista de todos os eles que correspondam a procura
manchetes = '' # nossa futura string the manchetes
for manchete in manchetes_html:
    manchetes += '{}\n'.format(manchete.text)
print(manchetes)
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/BrilliantLightheartedRegister)

Comment: obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: De nada @EdS, o mais importante é tentar perceber o que se passa, depois é sempre igual. Ainda bem que ajudei